# Will these 2 RAMs play nicely?

Tags: memory, ramdisk

**EDIT To the Original Question:**

I did some research and the old computer I discovered is a Dell Dimension 2400. According to the [SPEC Sheet](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/SYSTEMS/dim2400/en/sm_en/specs.htm) the RAM is PC2100 (266-MHz) or PC2700 (333-MHz) DDR SDRAM (non-ECC), will that work in my system which is running 2GB of PC3200 DDR 400MHZ RAM (In a configuration of 2 512mb sticks and 1GB stick) I have an open slot which can hold this 1 stick of 1GB. First - Will it even work? Second - If it will work will it help increase speed?

---

**Original Question:**

I have an old computer lying around and it struck me that I should take the RAM from it and see if it works in another computer I am using. The old computer does not work anymore so I cannot go to a site like crucial and run a simple test.

I pulled the stick out of the computer and it says it is a Samsung 1GB DDR DIMM, Q.

[Here is a link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00076ZUZM) to the current stick I have in the computer that I am attempting to put the SAMSUNG stick into.

Here are the full numbers on the label of the stick of RAM from the old computer:

```
1GB, DDR DIMM, Q
AOTQD PO 129009.2
```

Then on the actual chips themselves it has these numbers:

```
SAMSUNG 646
K4H510838C-UCCC
H51 8 CMJ05816
```

If I was to put this stick into the computer and it is not compatable what would happen? I do not want to damage anything on my computer. Advice?

***A FINAL NOTE:*** After this question was answered and I installed RAM, it turns out that the RAM was DDR 3200 according to a crucial test despite the specs saying the computer did not support that type of RAM. Guess when I upgraded RAM in the old computer I purchased 3200. =>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RAM will work with your current setup. This is because, the current RAM you are having is DDR 400 Mhz, and the old one you have mentioned is also DDR Frequency N.A.

Only limitation you will have is the RAMs will automatically adjust to a frequency of the lower one.

For example, The current one has Freq. 400 MHz, and the older on has, say 333 MHz, then both will be clocked to 333 MHz. Rest will work fine, possibly improving the performance of your system.

As far as compatibility with motherboard is concerned, the computer wont start with the configuration, if not supported. No harm comes in trying that.

Comment: Thanks for the information, is there an easy way to test the speed before and after to see if I get a speed boost?

Answer (score 3):

BIOS will detect if the RAM is not compatible and let you know by halting with a warning indicating such.  No damage will be done by this.

If the RAM is compatible, I think BIOS may post a message saying it has detected new RAM, and ask if you want to continue booting into your OS.